# How do I write 301 redirects for links with PHP variables?

Tags: php, variables, redirect

Hello I have recently redirected my site away from an old site to link to a new site. I am looking to preserve as much google rankings as possible so have created a spreadsheet mapping all old links to new links and setup 301 redirects with the new company. The basic ones such as `/married.htm -> /weddings/ 301` worked straight away but all the ones with PHP variables in the link are still not working such as `/profile.php?artist=Eclipse -> /eclipse-band-scotland 301`. I would like to work out how to get these working as soon as possible I am guesisng it is just that they cant be read in their current format and they need a rewrite of some kind? At a loss though as to how to proceed.

Can anyone suggest what I can try to get...

```
/profile.php?artist=Eclipse -> /eclipse-band-scotland 301
```

...working and I can give it a go? Once I get that working I can apply to all the other ones! Much obliged in advance. Chris.

Comment: htaccess rules is one way to do it.

Comment: please post your code `php` or `.htaccess` so we can help you

Comment: take a look of the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php, could also do by other way

Comment: I don't have access to the .htaccess the code above is what I added to the hosts edit box for these. The simple one works but the one with PHP variable in the link doesn't. If you can please suggest a fix for php link above I will try it out.

Comment: what is the "hosts edit box" ?

Comment: Well I cant access the .htaccess file or any files directly using FTP so they provide an edit box that I just drop in the 301 redirects. /married.htm -> /weddings/ 301 works fine but /profile.php?artist=Eclipse -> /eclipse-band-scotland 301 doesnt. I presume this just gets saved as into the .htaccess. So I am looking for someone who knows how these php variable links can be used in 301 redirects and work correctly.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas I thought this would be a fairly simple reformatting job? Must have happened to others before.